# Inflater can't find constructor

Tags: android, view, inflate

This is probably the most annoying error I have ever encountered. When I go to inflate a custom view and pass it to and activity, I get this:

```
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{android.appion.ResourceManager.UI/android.appion.ResourceManager.UI.ARMHomescreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.appion.ResourceManager.NUI.ARMPublicService$WorkBench
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #62: Error inflating class android.appion.ResourceManager.NUI.ARMPublicService$WorkBench
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:503)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1654)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.appion.ResourceManager.UI.ARMHomescreen.onCreate(ARMHomescreen.java:141)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     ... 11 more
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: WorkBench(Context,AttributeSet)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:660)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:477)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:475)
02-02 10:34:08.080: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(839):     ... 23 more
```

What I took away from this was "Hey, I must have forgotten to add AttributeSet to my View, dummy", this is not so! My constructor is perfect from what I can tell. Can anyone tell what I'm missing or if eclipse is screwing me rectally?

```
public class WorkBench extends GridView {
    private final String TAG = "WorkBench";

    // The position in the WorkArea
    public String TITLE;
    private String[] DEVICE = new String[6];

    private int mSelection;
    public WorkBench(Context context) {super(context);}
    public WorkBench(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setAdapter(new GridAdapter());
    }
    public WorkBench(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

... Rest of class definition
```

Where I'm calling the WorkBench (WorkBench and this function are in a service, that's why I cast to Activity)

```
public WorkBench createBench(Context context) {
    return (WorkBench)((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.workbench);
}
```

And the XML

```
<view               class="android.appion.ResourceManager.NUI.ARMPublicService$WorkBench"
    android:id="@+id/workbench"
    android:background="@+drawable/woodtexture1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="2" />
```

Any tips will be helpful, thanks
~Aedon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your `class` is wrong, or your class is wrong.

You have:

```
class="android.appion.ResourceManager.NUI.ARMPublicService$WorkBench"
```

This will work if, and only if, `WorkBench` is a static inner class. Your class definition for `WorkBench`, shown above, is for a non-static inner class.

Since it is impossible to use a non-static inner class in this case, your `class` is probably fine -- just adjust `WorkBench` to be a static inner class, and you should be in OK shape.

Comment: Ah I see.... I can't make the inner class static though, it needs to access data from the outer class frequently. As you say above it is impossible to use a non-static class in this case, is there a way to maybe change the case to accommodate a non-static inner class? Or do ALL custom views have to be static period?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA: "I can't make the inner class static though, it needs to access data from the outer class frequently. " -- you don't have a choice. "Or do ALL custom views have to be static period?" -- all custom views must be standalone classes or static inner classes. It is physically impossible to instantiate a non-static inner class from outside.